# Radio, Cannot read property 'focusVisible' of null

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, gatsby

I have a little tricky setup with Gatsby 1.9 and react-next with React 16.5.2 and Material UI 3.2.2

I have no idea what goes into conflict with what, but basically any time I try to use Radio or RadioGroup components I get this weird error (see below)

Unfortunately, I can't migrate to Gatsby 2.0 for a proper React 16 support.

Maybe somebody can figure out what is the problem exactly and I can then override some dependency version?

Here is the error:
[image]

Comment: I get this warning in console when I run the sample within my setup: ```Warning: `WithStyles(ButtonBase)` uses `getDerivedStateFromProps` but its initial state is undefined. This is not recommended. Instead, define the initial state by assigning an object to `this.state` in the constructor of `WithStyles(ButtonBase)`. This ensures that `getDerivedStateFromProps` arguments have a consistent shape.```

Comment: Please post some of your code here

Comment: There are many things that you should pay attention to in the precess of migrating Gatsby1.9 to 2.0,like you should install react-dom,so maybe at least post your package.json and package-lock.json.

Comment: @Root I don't intend to migrate from Gatsby v1 to Gatsby v2, at least not in the forceable future
All code is running on Gatsby v1 at the moment, with react-next applied to support React 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly enough, problem was resolved by removing node_modules completely and reinstalling all packages.

Maybe there was some kind of conflict?